# Are solutions to the Beltrami Equations necessarily smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $ a $, $ b $ and $ c $ be real constants such that $ \Delta \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} a c - b^{2} > 0 $. The *Beltrami Equations* are defined as the following system of PDE’s on the domain $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $:
$$
u_{x} =   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Delta}} (b v_{x} + c v_{y}), \qquad
u_{y} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Delta}} (a v_{x} + b v_{y}).
$$

> **Question:** Are solutions $ u $ and $ v $ of this system necessarily in $ C^{\infty} \! \left( \Bbb{R}^{2} \right) $?

My question stems from similarities I see between this system and the Cauchy-Riemann Equations in PDE form.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you have phrased this as a PDE you need some boundary data / initial data to determine the solution(s). What is this here? By considering $0 = \partial_y u_x - \partial_x u_y$ we get a PDE for $v$ alone. Due to the constrain on $\Delta$ this PDE will be [elliptical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation). Your question could then perhaps be answered by the [elliptical regularity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator#Elliptic_regularity_theorem).

Comment: @Winther: Hi Winther. I’m not imposing any boundary conditions here. My question is simply whether *any* solution pair $ (u,v) $ is necessarily smooth. For example, solutions of the Cauchy-Riemann equations (in PDE form) are necessarily smooth (probably as a consequence of some regularity theorem); boundary conditions don’t have to be specified. Also, as we don’t know if $ u $ has second-order partial derivatives, how can we attach meaning to $ \partial_{y} u_{x} $ and $ \partial_{x} u_{y} $?

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for clarifying. Hopefully someone more qualified than me will be able to answer this for you.

Comment: This is true. See section 15.2 (Beltrami equation with constant coefficients) of the [Astala-Iwaniec-Martin book](https://books.google.com/books?id=5aOgM9XRiXUC). Put $h=0$ there and follow the proof; you will see that a linear change of variables (both dependent and independent) turns the equation into the Cauchy-Riemann equation. The calculations are tedious.

Answer (score 0):

If $ (u,v) $ is a $ C^{1} $-solution pair, then it is, in fact, a $ C^{\infty} $-solution pair. To prove this, let $ F_{f} $ denote the distribution corresponding to a locally integrable function $ f $ on $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $. As
$$
{\partial_{x}}(F_{u}) = F_{u_{x}}, \quad
{\partial_{y}}(F_{u}) = F_{u_{y}}, \quad
{\partial_{x}}(F_{v}) = F_{v_{x}}  \quad \text{and} \quad
{\partial_{y}}(F_{v}) = F_{v_{y}},
$$
the Beltrami Equations imply the following relations:
$$
  {\partial_{x}}(F_{u})
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Delta}}
  [b \cdot {\partial_{x}}(F_{v}) + c \cdot {\partial_{y}}(F_{v})]
  \quad \text{and} \quad
  {\partial_{y}}(F_{u})
= - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Delta}}
    [a \cdot {\partial_{x}}(F_{v}) + b \cdot {\partial_{y}}(F_{v})].
$$
Then as $ {\partial_{xy}}(F_{u}) = {\partial_{yx}}(F_{u}) $, we obtain
$$
  0
= a \cdot {\partial_{xx}}(F_{v}) + 2 b \cdot {\partial_{xy}}(F_{v}) +
  c \cdot {\partial_{yy}}(F_{v}).
$$
The distribution $ F_{v} $ therefore belongs to the kernel of a second-order elliptic operator, so by elliptic regularity, we have $ F_{v} = F_{w} $ for some $ w \in C^{\infty} \! \left( \Bbb{R}^{2} \right) $. It now follows from continuity that $ v = w $, so we can conclude that $ u,v \in C^{\infty} \! \left( \Bbb{R}^{2} \right) $.

---

**Note:** If we only assume that $ (u,v) $ is a continuous pair with first-order partial derivatives that are not assumed to be continuous, then it is most likely that we still have the same conclusion. One has to study Section $ 15.2 $ of the reference kindly provided by Mice Elf in his comment above.